# Streamlining array to get total for each key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to build arrays based off of two queries, one in mysql one on db2. I've built the main arrays, the first dealing with product info and the 2nd dealing with customer info but they have some values in common.

This is working as far as structure but I've been trying to build a final array to contain data from the initial arrays that will build a report.

For now, I'm just going to try and output a report or csv file for each sku_id from the first query, and the total number/ quantity from the 2nd query.

The 2nd query/array contain multiple attributes on a per product/customer basis.

```
(
[1] => 2
)
Array
(
[1] => 5
)
Array
(
[1] => 14
)
```

Basically, I pulled three records from the first table for sku_id '1' and matched those three records in db2 for the same sku. Each element corresponds to a customer, so this structure says "customer A had 2 of sku_id 1, customer B had 5 of sku_id 1 and customer C had 14 of sku_id 1'

For the purpose of the report, each line will be for each sku so I want to instead output this as:

```
array
(
[1] => 21
)
```

Showing that overall, sku_id 1 had a total of 21. So I still want to keep my initial arrays structured like they are, but I want to modify my final array to just give me line items for the report.

How can I do that?

```
$skuQuery = "
    SELECT 
        sku_id,
        dealer_id,
        locations,
        s.sku_group_id as groupID,
        s.frame as frame,
        s.cover1 as cover,
        s.color1 as color,
        start_date - interval 7 day as start_date
    from products p
    inner join skus s on p.sku_id = s.id
    where curdate() between p.start_date and p.expire_date
    group by sku_id, dealer_id
    limit 3";

$skuRslt = mysqli_query($conn,$skuQuery);
while($skuRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($skuRslt)){

    $skuResult['sku_id'] = $skuRow;

    $dealerQuery = "
        SELECT
              cstnoc,
              sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
          from table
            where cstnoc = {$skuRow['dealer_id']}
            AND framec = {$skuRow['frame']}
              AND colr1c = {$skuRow['color']}
              AND covr1c =  {$skuRow['cover']}
              AND extd2d >= " . str_replace('-', '', $skuRow['start_date']) . "
        group by cstnoc, framec
    ";

    $dealerRslt = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $dealerQuery);

    $dealerResult = [];
    foreach($skuResult as $skuRow){
        while($dealerRow = odbc_fetch_array($dealerRslt)){
                if ( !isset($dealerResult[$dealerRow['CSTNOC']]) ) {
                    $dealerResult[$dealerRow['CSTNOC']] = 0;
                }
                $dealerResult[$dealerRow['CSTNOC']] += $dealerRow['TOTALQTY'];
        }
    }

    $skuTots = array_fill_keys(array_unique(array_column($skuResult, 'sku_id')), 0);
    foreach ($skuResult as $rec) {
        $skuTots[$rec['sku_id']] += $dealerResult[$rec['dealer_id']];
    }
    print_r($skuTots);
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the print out for my first two arrays:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku_id] => 1
            [dealer_id] => 1976
            [locations] => 1
            [groupID] => 1
            [frame] => 1051
            [cover] => 1150
            [color] => 99
            [start_date] => 2018-03-
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku_id] => 1
            [dealer_id] => 5400
            [locations] => 1
            [groupID] => 1
            [frame] => 1051
            [cover] => 1150
            [color] => 99
            [start_date] => 2017-04-
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [sku_id] => 1
            [dealer_id] => 11316
            [locations] => 1
            [groupID] => 1
            [frame] => 1051
            [cover] => 1150
            [color] => 99
            [start_date] => 2017-02-
        )


)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CSTNOC] => 1976
            [TOTALQTY] => 2
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [CSTNOC] => 5400
            [TOTALQTY] => 5
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [CSTNOC] => 11316
            [TOTALQTY] => 14
        )
)
```

And here is an example of my end result I'm trying to achieve:

In the below example, sku_id, groupID and location would come directly from the first query. Days is the number of days between start_date (from query 1) and curDate(). Qty is orqtyc from query 2 and Average is a calculation based on locations, days and qty. Each row is based on a different customer, so even though the below example is for one sku, the rows signify a different customer with different locations, qty, etc.

```
SKU_id    |   groupID   | locations (n) | Days (x) | Qty(q) | Average (x/(q/n))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123              1            3             120         15           24
123              1            2             12          6            4
```

The Report or CSV would then only show one line item for the above:

```
SKU   |   Group   |   Average Days   |   Total units sold
123   |     1     |        28        |          21
```

Basically, for every sku I'm getting those records and then I need  to do those calculations by row, and get a total of those values for each sku. The report will only have one line item per sku.

Comment: Whoever designed a system using two different DB systems to hold the data that has to be joined together owes you a lifetime supply of headache pills!!

Comment: Trust me I agree! They just started using MySQL a couple years ago but we have new challenges every day where we have to bring these data sources together in a new way, and this is one example

Comment: You show the two queries, but what will the final array structure look like?

Comment: So my first 2 arrays basically just return the selected values from each database query. The final array is what I want for the report version on a sku level. So right now I want each array key to be the sku ID and the  value to be the total quantity 'orqtyc', if that makes sense. I put an example about halfway through the code. Eventually I want to have a formula for averages that will go in this array too

Comment: I have print out of the other two arrays but it will be a minute before I can post them

Comment: If the row level key is the SKU, and each of the two source arrays have only one "row" per SKU, then it should be pretty simple. Just step through the two arrays one at a time, and set their data in the 3rd array using the SKU as the index to the row.

Comment: That may be where it's tricky , because every sku may have 100 or more rows in the query because it's really a group by dealer and sku. So I may get 7 rows for sku id 1 because each row is for a different dealer that bought that sku. I'm updating my question to show the first 2 arrays if that helps.

Comment: @SloanThrasher would it be easier if I posted a mockup of what I want the whole array to potentially look like for the CSV/report?

Comment: I updated with a better idea of my end goal

Comment: Instead of building the dealerResult array fresh for each row in skuRslt, add to it so that when you're done going through all of the skus, you can go through it and join the data between the two arrays. You'll need to index it in a way where you can join the data from the two arrays, and do your calculations. Also, you can calc the number of days in the sku SQL statement. ```DATEDIFF(NOW(),(start_date - interval 7 day)) as num_days```

Comment: Why doesn't this question just present the two arrays (shown at the end of the question) and ask how to convert those datapoints into the desired result?  Do we need all of the other stuff?